# IndexedDB giving error while creating the object store

Tags: javascript, eslint, indexeddb

While creating the object store i am getting the linting error. How to rewrite the code to fix this errors

**Code snippet**

```
    const self = this;

const IDBConfig = {
  name: 'Cache_responses',
  version: 1,
  stores: [
    {
      name: 'request_api',
      Path: 'url'
    },
    {
      name: 'response_result',
      Path: 'url'
    }
  ]
};

const createIndexedDb = ({name, version, stores}) => {
const request = self.indexedDB.open(name, version);
  return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    request.onupgradeneeded = e => {
      const db = e.target.result;
      
      stores.map(({name,Path}) => { //1.'name' is already declared in upper scope. 
      //2.expected to return a value in arrow function

        if(!db.objectStoreNames.contains(name)) {
          db.createObjectStore(name, {Path});
        }
      })
    }
   request.onsuccess = () => resolve(request.result);
   request.onerror = () => reject(request.error);
  })
};
```

I am getting these two errors while mapping the name and path. I am not sure why it is showing? How to rewrite this part or simplify this part?

Comment: 1) ignore the error or configure your linter to not use that rule. 2) use a `function` instead, or configure your linter to not use that role. 3. the missing call to `resolve`/`reject` (unused variables) are what the linter should actually complain about.

Comment: Thanks for your response. For your 3rd point, i have updated the code. Can you tell me the 2nd point of yours? How to rewrite that instead of arrow function?

Comment: What linter do you use?

Comment: ESLint extension i am using